# Css Genesis Theme - Changing Font Color In Menu

Tags: css, menu, stylesheet

I am sure there is a simple fix but I cant figure it out :-(
I am working on a test site http://www.mypinkluggage.net, and I want to change the menu font color from green to cream. I cant figure out how to overide the color..
This is all the menu css code:

```
    /* Header / Primary / Secondary Navigation
------------------------------------------------------------ */

.menu-primary,
.menu-secondary,
#header .menu {
    background: url(http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/NavNew1.png);
    clear: both;
    color: #758a94;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: auto;
    height: 75px;
}

.menu-primary,
.menu-secondary {
    padding: 0 25px;
}

#header .menu {
    background: none;
    float: right;
    margin: 15px 0 0;
}

.menu-primary,
.menu-secondary {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

#nav,
#subnav {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e3eaee;
}

.menu-primary ul,
.menu-secondary ul,
#header .menu ul {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.menu-primary li,
.menu-secondary li,
#header .menu li {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 12px auto;
    font-weight: bold;

}

.menu-primary a,
.menu-secondary a,
#header .menu a {

    font-color: #font-color: #fbf5db;;
    display: block;
    font-family: Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    padding: 13px 15px 12px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#header .menu a {
    padding: 8px 15px 7px;
}

#header .menu a {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.menu-primary li a:active,
.menu-primary li a:hover,
.menu-primary .current_page_item a,
.menu-primary .current-cat a,
.menu-primary .current-menu-item a,
.menu-secondary li a:active,
.menu-secondary li a:hover,
.menu-secondary .current_page_item a,
.menu-secondary .current-cat a,
.menu-secondary .current-menu-item a,
#header .menu li a:active,
#header .menu li a:hover,
#header .menu .current_page_item a,
#header .menu .current-cat a,
#header .menu .current-menu-item a {
    background-color: #e04861;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #244c5e;
    height: 22px 22px;


}

#header .menu li a:active,
#header .menu li a:hover,
#header .menu .current_page_item a,
#header .menu .current-cat a,
#header .menu .current-menu-item a {
    background-color: #f0f4f6;
}

.menu-primary li li a,
.menu-primary li li a:link,
.menu-primary li li a:visited,
.menu-secondary li li a,
.menu-secondary li li a:link,
.menu-secondary li li a:visited,
#header .menu li li a,
#header .menu li li a:link,
#header .menu li li a:visited {
    background: none;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #e3eaee;
    border-top: none;
    color: #244c5e;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 7px 5px;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: none;
    width: 128px;
    margin: 10px auto;
}

.menu-primary li li:last-child a,
.menu-secondary li li:last-child a,
#header .menu li li:last-child a { 
    border: none; 
}

.menu-primary li li a:active,
.menu-primary li li a:hover,
.menu-secondary li li a:active,
.menu-secondary li li a:hover,
#header .menu li li a:active,
#header .menu li li a:hover {
    background: none;

}

.menu-primary li ul,
.menu-secondary li ul,
#header .menu li ul {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #e3eaee;
    border-top: 0;
    height: auto;
    left: -9999px;
    margin: 0 0 0 -1px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 140px;
    z-index: 9999;
}

#header .menu li ul {
    margin: 0;
}

.menu-primary li ul a,
.menu-secondary li ul a,
#header .menu li ul a {
    width: 130px;
}

.menu-primary li ul ul,
.menu-secondary li ul ul,
#header .menu li ul ul {
    margin: -32px 0 0 150px;
}

.menu li:hover ul ul,
.menu li.sfHover ul ul {
    left: -9999px;
}

.menu li:hover,
.menu li.sfHover {
    position: static;
}

ul.menu li:hover>ul,
ul.menu li.sfHover ul,
#header .menu li:hover>ul,
#header .menu li.sfHover ul {
    left: auto;
}

#header .menu li a.sf-with-ul {
    padding-right: 25px;
}

.menu li a .sf-sub-indicator,
.menu li li a .sf-sub-indicator,
.menu li li li a .sf-sub-indicator {
    position: absolute;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}

#header .menu li a .sf-sub-indicator,
#header .menu li li a .sf-sub-indicator,
#header .menu li li li a .sf-sub-indicator {
    background: url(images/icon-down.png) no-repeat;
    height: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 3px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    top: 12px;
    width: 16px;
}

#header .menu li li a .sf-sub-indicator,
#header .menu li li li a .sf-sub-indicator {
    background: url(images/icon-right.png) no-repeat;
}

#wpadminbar li:hover ul ul {
    left: 0;
}
```

So which bit do I change?

Thank you for any help!

EDIT: HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>PolicePR – My WordPress Blog</title>
<meta name="description" content="My Wordpress Blog" />
<meta name="robots" content="noodp,noydir" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <style type="text/css">
            .slide-excerpt { width: 50%; }
            .slide-excerpt { bottom: 0; }
            .slide-excerpt { right: 0; }
            .flexslider { max-width: 920px; max-height: 400px; }
            .slide-image { max-height: 400px; } 
        </style>
        <style type="text/css"> 
            @media only screen 
            and (min-device-width : 320px) 
            and (max-device-width : 480px) {
                .slide-excerpt { display: none !important; }
            }            
        </style> <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="PolicePR &raquo; Feed" href="http://mypinkluggage.net/feed/" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="PolicePR &raquo; Comments Feed" href="http://mypinkluggage.net/comments/feed/" />
<link rel="canonical" href="http://mypinkluggage.net/" />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='afm-widget-style-css'  href='http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-content/plugins/addcents/inc/afmFieldsCSS/style.css?ver=3.8.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='afm-widget-style2-css'  href='http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-content/plugins/addcents/inc/afmFieldsCSS/options.css?ver=3.8.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='open-sans-css'  href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans%3A300italic%2C400italic%2C600italic%2C300%2C400%2C600&#038;subset=latin%2Clatin-ext&#038;ver=3.8.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css'  href='http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=3.8.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='admin-bar-css'  href='http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css?ver=3.8.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='focus-child-theme-css'  href='http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-content/themes/focus/style.css?ver=2.0.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='slider_styles-css'  href='http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-content/plugins/genesis-responsive-slider/style.css?ver=0.9.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function w3tc_popupadmin_bar(url) {
                return window.open(url, '', 'width=800,height=600,status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes');
            }
        </script>
            <script type='text/javascript' src='http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.10.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://mypinkluggage.net/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="Shortcut Icon" href="http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-content/themes/focus/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<style type="text/css">#header { background: url(http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-content/themes/focus/images/header.png) no-repeat !important; }</style>
<style type="text/css" id="custom-background-css">
body.custom-background { background-color: #050226; background-image: url('http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/bg5.jpg'); background-repeat: repeat; background-position: top left; background-attachment: scroll; }
</style>
<style type="text/css" media="print">#wpadminbar { display:none; }</style>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html { margin-top: 32px !important; }
    * html body { margin-top: 32px !important; }
    @media screen and ( max-width: 782px ) {
        html { margin-top: 46px !important; }
        * html body { margin-top: 46px !important; }
    }
</style>
</head>
<body class="home page page-id-14 page-template-default logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support custom-background content-sidebar"><div id="wrap"><div id="header"><div class="wrap"><div id="title-area"><p id="title"><a href="http://mypinkluggage.net/" title="PolicePR">PolicePR</a></p><p id="description">My Wordpress Blog</p></div><div class="widget-area header-widget-area"><div id="search-4" class="widget widget_search"><div class="widget-wrap"><form method="get" class="searchform search-form" action="http://mypinkluggage.net/" role="search" ><input type="text" value="Search this website&#x2026;" name="s" class="s search-input" onfocus="if (&#039;Search this website&#x2026;&#039; === this.value) {this.value = &#039;&#039;;}" onblur="if (&#039;&#039; === this.value) {this.value = &#039;Search this website&#x2026;&#039;;}" /><input type="submit" class="searchsubmit search-submit" value="Search" /></form></div></div>
</div></div></div><div id="subnav"><div class="wrap"><ul id="menu-standard" class="menu genesis-nav-menu menu-secondary"><li id="menu-item-15" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-14 current_page_item menu-item-15"><a href="http://mypinkluggage.net/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-16" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-16"><a href="http://mypinkluggage.net/about/">About</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-17"><a href="http://mypinkluggage.net/contact-us/">Contact Us</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-18"><a href="http://mypinkluggage.net/privacy-policy/">Privacy Policy</a></li>
</ul></div></div><div id="inner"><div class="wrap"><div id="content-sidebar-wrap"><div id="content" class="hfeed"><div class="post-14 page type-page status-publish hentry entry"><h1 class="entry-title">This Is An Article Title</h1> 
<div class="entry-content"><h1>Heading 1</h1>
<p>This is the body text</p>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<h4>Heading 4</h4>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<a class="post-edit-link" href="http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-admin/post.php?post=14&amp;action=edit">(Edit)</a></div></div></div><div id="sidebar" class="sidebar widget-area"><div id="search-1" class="widget widget_search"><div class="widget-wrap"><form method="get" class="searchform search-form" action="http://mypinkluggage.net/" role="search" ><input type="text" value="Search this website&#x2026;" name="s" class="s search-input" onfocus="if (&#039;Search this website&#x2026;&#039; === this.value) {this.value = &#039;&#039;;}" onblur="if (&#039;&#039; === this.value) {this.value = &#039;Search this website&#x2026;&#039;;}" /><input type="submit" class="searchsubmit search-submit" value="Search" /></form></div></div>
<div id="categories-1" class="widget widget_categories"><div class="widget-wrap"><h4 class="widget-title widgettitle">Categories</h4>
        <ul>
<li class="cat-item-none">No categories</li>        </ul>
</div></div>
</div></div></div></div><div id="footer" class="footer"><div class="wrap"><div class="gototop"><p><a href="#wrap" rel="nofollow">Return to top of page</a></p></div><div class="creds"><p>Copyright &#x000A9;&nbsp;2014 · <a href="http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-login.php?action=logout&#038;_wpnonce=05127451ae">Log out</a></p></div></div></div></div><!-- Powered by WPtouch: 3.1.5 --><script type='text/javascript'>jQuery(document).ready(function($) {$(".flexslider").flexslider({controlsContainer: "#genesis-responsive-slider",animation: "slide",directionNav: 1,controlNav: 1,animationDuration: 800,slideshowSpeed: 4000    });  });</script><script type='text/javascript' src='http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-includes/js/admin-bar.min.js?ver=3.8.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-content/plugins/genesis-responsive-header/js/resize-header.js?ver=0.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-content/plugins/genesis-responsive-slider/js/jquery.flexslider.js?ver=0.9.2'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            var request, b = document.body, c = 'className', cs = 'customize-support', rcs = new RegExp('(^|\\s+)(no-)?'+cs+'(\\s+|$)');

            request = true;

            b[c] = b[c].replace( rcs, ' ' );
            b[c] += ( window.postMessage && request ? ' ' : ' no-' ) + cs;
        }());
    </script>
            <div id="wpadminbar" class="nojq nojs" role="navigation">
            <a class="screen-reader-shortcut" href="#wp-toolbar" tabindex="1">Skip to toolbar</a>
            <div class="quicklinks" id="wp-toolbar" role="navigation" aria-label="Top navigation toolbar." tabindex="0">
                <ul id="wp-admin-bar-root-default" class="ab-top-menu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-wp-logo" class="menupop"><a class="ab-item"  aria-haspopup="true" href="http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-admin/about.php" title="About WordPress"><span class="ab-icon"></span></a><div class="ab-sub-wrapper"><ul id="wp-admin-bar-wp-logo-default" class="ab-submenu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-about"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-admin/about.php">About WordPress</a>      </li></ul><ul id="wp-admin-bar-wp-logo-external" class="ab-sub-secondary ab-submenu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-wporg"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://wordpress.org/">WordPress.org</a>      </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-documentation"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://codex.wordpress.org/">Documentation</a>        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-support-forums"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://wordpress.org/support/">Support Forums</a>        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-feedback"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://wordpress.org/support/forum/requests-and-feedback">Feedback</a>     </li></ul></div>        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-site-name" class="menupop"><a class="ab-item"  aria-haspopup="true" href="http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-admin/">PolicePR</a><div class="ab-sub-wrapper"><ul id="wp-admin-bar-site-name-default" class="ab-submenu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-dashboard"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-admin/">Dashboard</a>     </li></ul><ul id="wp-admin-bar-appearance" class="ab-submenu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-themes"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-admin/themes.php">Themes</a>     </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-customize" class="hide-if-no-customize"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-admin/customize.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmypinkluggage.net%2F">Customize</a>     </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-widgets"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-admin/widgets.php">Widgets</a>      </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-menus"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-admin/nav-menus.php">Menus</a>        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-background"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-admin/themes.php?page=custom-background">Background</a>      </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-header"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-admin/themes.php?page=custom-header">Header</a>      </li></ul></div>        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-updates"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-admin/update-core.php" title="2 Plugin Updates"><span class="ab-icon"></span><span class="ab-label">2</span><span class="screen-reader-text">2 Plugin Updates</span></a>        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-comments"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-admin/edit-comments.php" title="0 comments awaiting moderation"><span class="ab-icon"></span><span id="ab-awaiting-mod" class="ab-label awaiting-mod pending-count count-0">0</span></a>       </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-content" class="menupop"><a class="ab-item"  aria-haspopup="true" href="http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-admin/post-new.php" title="Add New"><span class="ab-icon"></span><span class="ab-label">New</span></a><div class="ab-sub-wrapper"><ul id="wp-admin-bar-new-content-default" class="ab-submenu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-post"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-admin/post-new.php">Post</a>       </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-media"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-admin/media-new.php">Media</a>        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-link"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-admin/link-add.php">Link</a>       </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-page"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page">Page</a>        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-user"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-admin/user-new.php">User</a>       </li></ul></div>        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-edit"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-admin/post.php?post=14&#038;action=edit">Edit Page</a>     </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-w3tc" class="menupop"><a class="ab-item"  aria-haspopup="true" href="http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-admin/admin.php?page=w3tc_dashboard">Performance</a><div class="ab-sub-wrapper"><ul id="wp-admin-bar-w3tc-default" class="ab-submenu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-w3tc-pgcache-purge-post"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-admin/admin.php?page=w3tc_dashboard&#038;w3tc_flush_pgcache_purge_post&#038;post_id=14&#038;_wpnonce=02c8251f39">Purge From Cache</a>       </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-w3tc-empty-caches"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-admin/admin.php?page=w3tc_dashboard&#038;w3tc_flush_all&#038;_wpnonce=02c8251f39">Empty All Caches</a>        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-w3tc-modules" class="menupop"><div class="ab-item ab-empty-item"  aria-haspopup="true">Empty Modules</div><div class="ab-sub-wrapper"><ul id="wp-admin-bar-w3tc-modules-default" class="ab-submenu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-w3tc-flush-pgcache"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-admin/admin.php?page=w3tc_dashboard&#038;w3tc_flush_pgcache&#038;_wpnonce=02c8251f39">Empty Page Cache</a>       </li></ul></div>        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-w3tc-faq"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-admin/admin.php?page=w3tc_faq">FAQ</a>     </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-w3tc-support"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-admin/admin.php?page=w3tc_support"><span style="color: red; background: none;">Support</span></a>      </li></ul></div>        </li></ul><ul id="wp-admin-bar-top-secondary" class="ab-top-secondary ab-top-menu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-search" class="admin-bar-search"><div class="ab-item ab-empty-item" tabindex="-1"><form action="http://mypinkluggage.net/" method="get" id="adminbarsearch"><input class="adminbar-input" name="s" id="adminbar-search" type="text" value="" maxlength="150" /><input type="submit" class="adminbar-button" value="Search"/></form></div>      </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-my-account" class="menupop with-avatar"><a class="ab-item"  aria-haspopup="true" href="http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-admin/profile.php" title="My Account">Howdy, NJ1<img alt='' src='http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/d42775edef85b17b3cf8c745e3ee3c4d?s=26&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F1.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D26&amp;r=G' class='avatar avatar-26 photo' height='26' width='26' /></a><div class="ab-sub-wrapper"><ul id="wp-admin-bar-user-actions" class="ab-submenu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-user-info"><a class="ab-item" tabindex="-1" href="http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-admin/profile.php"><img alt='' src='http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/d42775edef85b17b3cf8c745e3ee3c4d?s=64&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F1.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D64&amp;r=G' class='avatar avatar-64 photo' height='64' width='64' /><span class='display-name'>NJ1</span></a>     </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-edit-profile"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-admin/profile.php">Edit My Profile</a>     </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-logout"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-login.php?action=logout&#038;_wpnonce=05127451ae">Log Out</a>        </li></ul></div>        </li></ul>          </div>
                        <a class="screen-reader-shortcut" href="http://mypinkluggage.net/wp-login.php?action=logout&#038;_wpnonce=05127451ae">Log Out</a>
                    </div>

        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post your html and specify which text you want to change color ?

Comment: I want to change the color of the items in the menu (About, Contact Us & Privacy Policy). It is governed by this rule: media="all"
a, a:visited  But I want to override it just for the menu text.

Comment: We need to see your HTML to find out which CSS rule is affecting that element.

Comment: OK I have edited my comment to include the html.

Comment: If I change the a:visited bit it changes the color, but then it also changes links everywhere on the page, and the links in the body of the text dont show. I want to overrule the color rule just for the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule to your style:

```
.menu-item a { color: blue; } /*  OR whatever color you want*/
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve it for you.

```
#menu-standard a {
   color: blue;
}
```